Alternative ways of counting lines in a file
I am trying to print the line number and character number when finding the index of a word. Can someone suggest an alternative way to enumerate lines without using enumerate in a for loop?
def find_word(f, word):
    g_indx = 0
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        indx = 0 
        while (indx != -1):
            indx = line.find(word, indx)
            if indx > -1:
                yield g_indx + indx
                indx += 1
        print(f'Line number {line_num}, characters amount = {len(line)}')
        g_indx += len(line)

try:
    with open("out.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        a = find_word(file, "Hello")
        print(list(a))
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File cannot be found")
except:
    print("File handling error")

The code is working, but I'm interested in other ways to print line numbers because I would like to avoid enumerate().

Why would you want to avoid enumerate()? This sort of use case is quite literally what it is intended to cover

You can simply initialize a counter variable to 0 and increment it each time through the loop.

Welcome to SO! Can you please explain why you don't want to use enumerate()? I think it is the best solution here.

Just increment the line_num variable yourself in the loop.
def find_word(f, word):
    g_indx = 0
    line_num = 1
    for line in f:
        indx = 0 
        while (indx != -1):
            indx = line.find(word, indx)
            if indx > -1:
                yield g_indx + indx
                indx += 1
        print(f'Line number {line_num}, characters amount = {len(line)}')
        g_indx += len(line)
        line_num += 1


If you don't want to use enumerate and the solution @Barmar suggested doesn't work for you, here's an alternative way to do what you need:
foo.txt:
Hello world
My name is John
The world, ah this world is a wonderful place

import re
from itertools import count


def find_word(file, target_word):
    search_pattern = re.compile(rf'{target_word}')
    g_idx = 0
    for line_num, line in zip(count(1), file):
        yield from (m.start(0) + g_idx for m in search_pattern.finditer(line))
        print(f'Line number {line_num}, characters amount = {len(line)}')
        g_idx += len(line)


with open('foo.txt') as f:
    result = list(find_word(f, 'world'))  # [6, 32, 47]

In my solution I use itertools.count(1) which for each line returns its sequence number in the source file. I also changed the way I search for words to a regular expression search. This can speed up the search for words in very long strings.
